# a practical question about matrix derivative with inverse and chain rule: dimension mismatch

Tags: matrices, derivatives, inverse, chain-rule

Recently, I was trying to take the following derivative 
$$
\dfrac{\partial (X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1}}{\partial V} 
$$
I was referring to [matrix cookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) to solve it, where I found several useful equations:

Equation (59) says:
$$
\dfrac{\partial Y^{-1}}{\partial x} = -Y^{-1}\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial x}Y^{-1}
$$
so, I think I have:
$$
\dfrac{\partial (X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1}}{\partial V^{-1}} = -(X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1} X^TX(X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1}
$$
and 
$$
\dfrac{\partial V^{-1}}{\partial V} = -V^{-1}V^{-1}
$$
According to the chain rule, it should be:
$$
\dfrac{\partial (X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1}}{\partial V} =\dfrac{\partial (X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1}}{\partial V^{-1}}\dfrac{\partial V^{-1}}{\partial V} = ((X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1} X^TX(X^TV^{-1}X)^{-1})^T V^{-1}V^{-1}
$$

However, I met one problem. $V$ is a matrix of size $(n, n)$ and $X$ is a matrix of size $(n, m)$. 
Then, the first half of the chain rule is of size of $(m, m)$, while the second half of the chain rule is of size $(n, n)$.

Please help me figure out what goes wrong.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: ur first line isn't an equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's define some intermediate variables
$$\eqalign{
 P &= V^{-1} \cr
 M &= X^TPX \cr
 F &= M^{-1} \cr
}$$
whose differentials are
$$\eqalign{
 dP &= -V^{-1}\,dV\,V^{-1} \cr
 dM &= X^T\,dP\,X \cr
 dF &= -M^{-1}\,dM\,M^{-1} \cr
}$$
That last differential is the one we're interested in, so let's successively substitute variables until we get back to $V$
$$\eqalign{
 dF &= -M^{-1}\,dM\,M^{-1} \cr
   &= -M^{-1}\,(X^T\,dP\,X)\,M^{-1} \cr
   &= -M^{-1}\,X^T\,(-V^{-1}\,dV\,V^{-1})\,X\,M^{-1} \cr
   &= M^{-1}\,X^T\,V^{-1}\,dV\,V^{-1}\,X\,M^{-1} \cr
   &= F\,X^T\,V^{-1}\,dV\,V^{-1}\,X\,F \cr
}$$
At this point, let's follow the prescription of Magnus & Neudecker for dealing with matrix-by-matrix derivatives, and vectorize both sides
$$\eqalign{
 d{\rm vec}(F) &= (V^{-1}\,X\,F)^T\otimes(F\,X^T\,V^{-1})\,d{\rm vec}(V) \cr
}$$
Which can be rearranged to the conventional looking result
$$\eqalign{
 \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} &= (V^{-1}\,X\,F)^T\otimes(F\,X^T\,V^{-1}) \cr
}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mind say something about how $\otimes$ is defined for two matrices? I am asking because `numpy` implementation only unfolds two matrices back to vectors and do a outer product of vectors, which contradicts an example I found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973559/outer-product-of-two-matrices)

Comment: Also, while thank you for your solution, which saves me. I am also looking for why my original solution is incorrect, so that I won't run into similar problem in the future. I sense that my understanding of chain rule for matrix calculus is incorrect. Do you mind help me figure that out?

Comment: The $\otimes$ symbol stands for the Kronecker product.  The Kronecker-vec identity is a well-known application. As for the chain rule, I do not use it for matrix-by-matrix derivatives, because it requires the use of double-dot products, and intermediate quantities which are 4th order tensors.  If you insist on using the chain rule, you should switch to index notation (and the Einstein summation convention).

Answer (score 0):

I don´t see how equation (59) should help. $V$ does not depend on $X$.

If $X$ is a square matrix then $\left(X^TV^{-1}X \right)^{-1}=X^{-1}V\left(X^{-1}\right)^T$

Let $X^{-1}=A$. We get $AVA^T$

You can see [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/MatrixCookBook.pdf) (page 9) that $$\frac{\partial AVA^T}{\partial V}= AA^T$$

Comment: Thanks. @calculus. But the inverse of X does not necessarily exist since it is not square.

Comment: @HaohanWang That´s true. I added this condition. I don´t have a better idea. I´m right that $V$ doesn´t depend on $X$ ?

Comment: Yes, $V$ does not depend on $X$

Comment: @HaohanWang As a said, in this case i don´t think that equation 59 can be used here.

Comment: do you mind elaborate why? If we see $Y$ as $X^{T}V^{-1}X$, $Y$ depends on $V$, isn't it?