# Obtain vector with ratio of vector elements with matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a (column) vector $x = (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$, I am trying to obtain a matrix with vectors of the ratios of the elements in $x$:

$$ R = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & x_2/x_1 & ... & x_n/x_1 \\
 x_1/x_2 & 1 & ... & x_n/x_2 \\
   &  &  \ddots  &  \\
 x_1/x_n & x_2/x_n & ...  & 1 \\
 \end{bmatrix}. $$

Is there a very simple matrix operation that generates $R$ from $x$ ? For now my solution is

$$R = Diag(x)^{-1} \boldsymbol{1} \otimes x,$$ where  $\boldsymbol{1}$ is an $n$-dimensional vector of ones and $\otimes$ is the outer product.

Comment: What exactly do you mea by outer product? Cf. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973559/outer-product-of-two-matrices)

Comment: $x \otimes y$ gives a matrix with elements $(x \otimes y)_{ij} = x_i y_j$.
So  I mean the tensor product. Surely not Kronecker product.

Comment: I noticed that I made an important typo .... now i fixd it.

Comment: Then if $x_1,...,x_n\neq 0$ what about $(x_1^{-1},...,x_n^{-1})^{tr}\otimes (x_1,...,x_n)^{tr}=R$?

Comment: tr is transpose? if so, yes.

Comment: btw $\neq0$  has to hold element-wise for R to be well defined.

Comment: Yes $tr$ transpose and by $x_1,..,x_n\neq 0$ I ment $x_j\neq 0$ for $j\in\{1,..,n\}$

Comment: If you define $.^{-1}:\mathbb{R^*}^n\rightarrow :\mathbb{R^*}^n,(x_1,...,x_n)^{tr}\mapsto (x_1 ^{-1},...,x_n^{-1})^{tr}$ (where $\mathbb{R^*}=\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$) it becomes $x^{-1}\otimes x$ which looks prettier